# How can I change the NN weights without affecting the gradients?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Say I have a simple NN:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.nn.utils import parameters_to_vector

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 3)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(3, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = torch.relu(x)        
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

net = Model()

opt = optim.Adam(net.parameters())
```

And also some features

```
features = torch.rand((3,1))
```

I can train it normally using:

```
for i in range(10):
    opt.zero_grad()
    out = net(features)
    loss = torch.mean(torch.square(torch.tensor(5) - torch.sum(out)))
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
```

However, I'm interested in updating the weights of each layer **after each example in the batch**. That is, updating the actual weight values by some amount that will be different for each layer.

I can print the parameters of each layer with:

```
for i in range(1):
    opt.zero_grad()
    out = net(features)
    print(parameters_to_vector(net.fc1.parameters()))
    print(parameters_to_vector(net.fc2.parameters()))
    print(parameters_to_vector(net.fc3.parameters()))
    loss = torch.mean(torch.square(torch.tensor(5) - torch.sum(out)))
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
```

How can I change the values of the weights before the backprop without affecting the gradient?

Say that I want the layers weights' to be updated according to the following functions:

```
def first_layer_update(weight):
    return weight + 1e-3*weight

def second_layer_update(weight):
    return 1e-2*weight

def third_layer_update(weight):
    return weight - 1e-1*weight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### - Using the `torch.no_grad` context manager.

This allows you to perform (in-place or out-of-place) operations on your tensors without Autograd keeping track of those changes. As [@user3474165](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3474165/user3474165) explained:

```
def first_layer_update(weight):
    with torch.no_grad():
        return weight + 1e-3*weight

def second_layer_update(weight):
    with torch_no_grad():
        return 1e-2*weight

def third_layer_update(weight):
    with torch.no_grad():
        return weight - 1e-1*weight
```

Or differently without altering your functions using the context manager when calling them:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    first_layer_update(net.fc1.weight)
    second_layer_update(net.fc2.weight)
    third_layer_update(net.fc3.weight)
```

---

##### - Using the `@torch.no_grad` decorator.

A variant is to use the `@torch.no_grad` decorator:

```
@torch.no_grad()
def first_layer_update(weight):
    return weight + 1e-3*weight

@torch.no_grad():
def second_layer_update(weight):
    return 1e-2*weight

@torch.no_grad():
def third_layer_update(weight):
    return weight - 1e-1*weight
```

And call these with: `first_layer_update(net.fc1.weight)`, `second_layer_update(net.fc2.weight)`, etc...

---

##### - Mutating `torch.Tensor.data`.

An alternative to wrapping your operations with the [`torch.no_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html) context is to mutate the weights using their `data` attribute. This means calling your functions with:

```
>>> first_layer_update(net.fc1.weight.data)
>>> second_layer_update(net.fc2.weight.data)
>>> third_layer_update(net.fc3.weight.data)
```

Which would mutate the weights (*not the biases*) of the three layers with their respective update policies.

---

In a nutshell, if you want to mutate all parameters of a `nn.Module` you can either do:

```
>>> with torch.no_grad():
...     update_policy(parameters_to_vector(net.layer.parameters()))
```

Or

```
>>> update_policy(parameters_to_vector(net.layer.parameters().data))
```

Comment: Nice. This seems more efficient than a `for loop`. Will both methods update the weights after each example (which is what I'm looking for) or once per batch? And just to clarify, both methods will have the same effect right? That is, the gradients will not be affected.

Comment: Indeed the gradients won't be affected by those changes. If you want to apply a function to all parameters (weight + bias) of the layer, then you are better off using your approach instead of a `for` loop, along with the `torch.no_grad` context manager. This means wrapping `first_layer_update(parameters_to_vector(net.fc1.parameters()))` with a `torch.no_grad` context or decorator.

Comment: Great. And will both methods update the weights after each example (which is what I'm looking for) or once per batch?

Comment: Actually, you can still  mutate `torch.nn.utils.parameters_to_vector(net.fc1.parameters()).data`, so both methods work with `parameters_to_vector`. To answer your question if you do one mutation per gradient descent then you will have one update per batch (if by *example* you mean batch element then it won't be *after each example* but after each batch).

Comment: Okay thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From the pytorch [docs](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-change-the-weights-of-a-pytorch-model/41279), you're basically on the right track. You can loop over all the parameters in each layer and then add to them directly

```py
with torch.no_grad():
  for param in layer.parameters():
    param.weight += 1e-3  # or whatever
```